# Force to POST dynamic select including empty value

Tags: arrays, post, select, null

I have multiple select with the same name like this :

```
<select name="test[]"><option>blah....</option></select>              
<select name="test[]"><option>blah....</option></select>              
<select name="test[]"><option>blah....</option></select>              
<select name="test[]"><option>blah....</option></select>
```

in php code i have :

```
$atest = $_POST['test'];
print_r($atest);
```

But, I got only data from not empty select, how to force $_POST to include all select disregarding it has value or not, so the array contains always 4 items.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`Multiple select` you can use

```
<select name="test[]" size="7" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
   <option value="4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

After request you check `$_POST['test']` is `array` that contains selected options

```
$test = $_POST['test'];
var_dump($test);
```

Comment: No, I need multiple select for data entry, not multiple value in single select. Because each select is inside table, and save all of them to different row in database. BTW thanks for your answer.

Comment: If multiple select, you `loop` and display select tag ?